Trying to redirect user from a booking page in django
This is my first Django project and I am really struggling. It is a simple booking app where the logged in user is on a page with a form to make a booking and a list of current bookings. I can make the page work and make a booking but the info in the form isnt cleared and if the page is refreshed it makes the booking again. To solve this, I think I need the page to redirect to a success page after the booking is made. When I try to do this, I get a "NoReverseMatch" error and am told that it is "not a valid view function or pattern name."
Here are the url patterns of booking.urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name='home'),
    path("booking/", views.booking, name='booking'),
    path('my_bookings/', views.my_bookings, name='my_bookings'),
    path('edit_booking/<int:booking_id>', views.edit_booking, name='edit_booking'),
    path('delete_booking/<int:booking_id>', views.delete_booking, name='delete_booking'),
    path('success_booking/', views.success_booking, name='success_booking'),
]

Here are some parts of the booking.views.py:
def my_bookings(request):
    bookings = Booking.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    booking_form = BookingForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        booking_form = BookingForm(data=request.POST)
        if booking_form.is_valid():
            booking = booking_form.save(commit=False)
            booking.user = request.user
            booking.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/booking_delete/'))

    return render(
        request, 
        "booking/booking_list.html",
        {
            'booking_form' : booking_form,
            'bookings': bookings,
        },
    )



And here is the snippet of booking_list.html that deals with the submit button:
<div class="col-md-4 mb-4 mt-3">
          <div>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <form id="bookingForm" method="post"
              style="margin-top: 1.3em;">
              {{ booking_form | crispy }}
              {% csrf_token %}
              <button id="BookingButton" type="submit"
                class="btn btn-lg btn-light">Make A Booking</button>
                <!-- <a class="btn btn-light btn-edit" href="{% url 'my_bookings' %}">Make Booking</a> -->
            </form>
            {% else %}
            <p>Log in to make a booking</p>
            {% endif %}
          </div>

I know that I lack understanding of how this all works. I have tried altering the urls file and using DTL for the submit button. I have tried different arguaments within the HttpResponseRedirect() function but I am really lost!!!

There are 2 issue with this line
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/booking_delete/'))


no need to use HttpResponseRedirect.
reverse or reverse_lazy take url name parameter to retrive url not url itself.

Update this line code should work
from django.urls import reverse
return redirect(reverse('booking_delete'))


And of cause the name has to exist in urlpatterns.

If I understand you right your goal is to redirect user to another url on form succes completetion instead of refreshing a form page once again.
First of all your use of reverse() is not correct.
reverse() concept is for view call by name rather then by URL.
In your case you call HttpResponseRedirect() which accepts URL as string. But you attempt to pass reverse() method which "converts" view name to URL under the hood.
By the other words: you want to use redirect() but in this case URL has to be passed or reverse() method contains view name.
But if you like Django to build URL path for you reverse() is really convenient:
Once you set a name for a view :
app_name = "booking"
path('delete_booking/<int:booking_id>', views.delete_booking, name='delete_booking')

You can use this name across your project to avoid hard-coding and do some extra job in a future since you need just to change URL in urls.py and reverse() method will use updated URL across the project in all spots where a view called by name.
Therefore you can change your code as follows using reverse():
if booking_form.is_valid():
            booking = booking_form.save(commit=False)
            booking.user = request.user
            booking.save()
            return redirect(reverse('delete_booking'))

It's good practice to use a view's name in templates as well:
<a href="{% url 'view_name' %}">

Once your project becomes bigger it's useful to add app_name variable for each app's url.py module. It allows you access to particular view name through the app_name.
reverse('app_name:view_name')

Same works fine with Django templates:
<a href="{% url 'app_name:view_name' %}">


Thanks for your reply. I followed your suggestions but I still get a "NoReverseMatch" error? How do I add my changes here?

For better understanding your issue could you please update your original code with the final one causes this exception. An provide some exception traceback.

Thanks. I solved the issue. I was it was looking for the booking ID. "return redirect(reverse('booking:success_booking', args=[booking.id]))"

Glad to hear that. Obviously, if your view accepts an input value it must be passed with args as mentioned in Docs I provided with reverse() link.

I was missing the booking ID from my view:
def my_bookings(request):
bookings = Booking.objects.filter(user=request.user)
booking_form = BookingForm()
if request.method == "POST":
    booking_form = BookingForm(data=request.POST)
    if booking_form.is_valid():
        booking = booking_form.save(commit=False)
        booking.user = request.user
        booking.save()
        print('booking id', booking.id)
        return redirect(reverse('booking:success_booking', args=[booking.id]))

return render(
    request, 
    "booking/booking_list.html",
    {
        'booking_form' : booking_form,
        'bookings': bookings,
    },
)

